# Составить запрос sql с выборкой

Tags: sql, sql-server

Сделать выборку содержащую: id линии, id сотрудника, чаще других отвечавших на звонки линии, количество звонков этого сотрудника на этой линии.

[image: База данных]

```
select л.id, сл.Сотрудник, count(з.Сотрудник) Количество_Звонков
from Линии л, Сотрудники_Линии сл, Звонки з,Сотрудники с
where с.id=сл.Сотрудник and л.id=сл.Линия and з.Сотрудник=с.id and л.id=з.Линия
group by л.id,сл.Сотрудник
order by л.id,Количество_Звонков desc
```

Мой код, я тут нахожу звонки по всем сотрудникам, но как вывести только максимальные, не могу понять.

Comment: Добавьте к запросу схему таблиц, пример данных, ожидаемый результат и, само собой, свой запрос, который должен этот результат вернуть, но не работает/неправильно работает и тп. В противном случае Ваш вопрос скорее всего будет закрыт как оффтопик. SO - не сервис для написания кода либо решения ДЗ.

Comment: *как вывести только максимальные* `TOP 1 WITH TIES`.

Comment: Akina, а как можно применить ваш метод для вывода максимальных для каждой линии , только начал учить язык поэтому интересуюсь

Comment: Сообщите версию SQL Server, в которой вы пишете запросы

Comment: sql server  ssms 2017

Answer (score 0):

Когда записи отсортированы, нужно обернуть еще в селект и взять первую запись, это будет запись с максимальным знчением

```
Select * from (
select л.id, сл.Сотрудник, count(з.Сотрудник) Количество_Звонков
from Линии л, Сотрудники_Линии сл, Звонки з,Сотрудники с
where с.id=сл.Сотрудник and л.id=сл.Линия and з.Сотрудник=с.id and л.id=з.Линия
group by л.id,сл.Сотрудник
order by л.id,Количество_Звонков desc)
Where rownum=1
```

Comment: последнюю строчку подчёркивает и запрос не срабатывает

Comment: еще бы запрос не срабатывал - он неправильный

Comment: не подскажите как правильно версия ssms 2017